# how to compare two numpy arrays with unequal length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays of unequal length. I would like to compare the two arrays for mismatch at index.
for example in these numpy arrays. The number of mismatches are

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 0,  1, 1])
b = np.array([1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1])
```

expected output : 3  ( three mismatches at index 0,3 and 5)

Comment: Seems like you can simply compare matching size arrays and then add indices for difference in shapes as mismatches as well.

Comment: slice the longer one so they match: `a != b[:5]`

Comment: Thank you @pavel  I improvised on your responses.

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj I improvised on your responses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment above.

Assuming we don't know which of the arrays is the longer one:

```
def foo(a, b):
    # Get equal length arrays
    c = a[: min([a.shape[0], b.shape[0]])]
    d = b[: min([a.shape[0], b.shape[0]])]

    # now compare equal arrays
    mis = np.equal(c, d)
    
    # Add difference in shapes of arrays as mismatches
    mis = np.concatenate((mis, np.full(abs(a.shape[0] - b.shape[0]), False)))
    return np.where(~mis)[0].shape[0]

>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 0,  1, 1])
    b = np.array([1, 1, 0,  0, 1, 1])
>>> x = foo(a, b)
>>> x
Out: 3
```

EDIT: Oops... forgot to add a bitwise not to the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I got . built on @pavel and @hpaulj answers.

```
def comp(a, b):
    # Get equal length arrays
    c = a[: min([a.shape[0], b.shape[0]])]
    d = b[: min([a.shape[0], b.shape[0]])]

    # now compare equal arrays
    mis = np.sum(c != d)
    
    mis = mis + abs(a.shape[0]-b.shape[0])
    return mis

a = np.array([0, 1, 0,  1, 1, 0, 0, 1])
b = np.array([1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 1])
x = comp(a,b)
x
```